# Why must polynomials have degrees that are positive integers?

Tags: polynomials, definition

What's the benefit of knowing 'this' is a polynomial? And why should we care?

Comment: what do you mean by non-negative integral power?

Comment: I mean in order to be polynomial, Degree on the variables need to non-negative integral.

Comment: For one, it enables the polynomial to be represented by it's coefficients only. That would not be possible if the power degrees could be real-valued.

Comment: So we rule out $x^{-1}$ and $x^{1/2}$ and $x^{2+3i}$ and $x^{L_2[0,1]}$, etc.  This will be the smallest set containing $x$ and the constants and closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: Take a look at [signomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signomial) and [posynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posynomial).

Comment: That's akin to asking: why do integers have no fractional part? Or why do real numbers have no imaginary part?  Each number system (ring) is *useful* enough to be singled out and named. Generalizations may also be useful enough to be named, e.g. [Laurent polynomials,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) and [Puiseux series,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Polynomials are everywhere infinitely differentiable (not to mention defined and continuous!), and positive-degree polynomials in one variable are completely factorisable into linear factors over $\Bbb C$. If we allow negative powers, the example $\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined at $0$ and has no roots in $\Bbb C$. Thus polynomials as we currently define them are a very nice set of functions to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomials are obtained by means of addition and multiplication alone. That gives them many interesting properties such as continuity, differentiability, null $d+1^{th}$ derivative, ring algebra, known number of roots, connection to linear algebra via ODE's and Eigenvalues and many many more.

---

Generalized polynomials with negative integer powers can be rewritten as the ratio of a polynomial over a power and are of little interest ($x+4x^{-3}=\dfrac{x^4+4}{x^3}$). Rational fractions, i.e. the ratio of two polynomials, are richer and more important.

---

Generalized polynomials with rational exponents can also be turned to ordinary polynomials by a change of variable (e.g. $x^{3/2}+4x^{1/3}=y^9+4y^2$ with $x=y^6$). So nothing really new.

---

Finally, generalized polynomials with real exponents are not attractive. They cannot be defined on negative arguments (and fit poorly with complex numbers) and don't enjoy the composition property "$p(q(x))$ is a polynomial". E.g.

$$(x+1)^\pi$$ cannot be written as a generalized polynomial in $x$.